# Mule 4/DW 2.0 - Convert Array to String so as to insert into database. Any function in DW 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Need help with converting the Audio array in the below example.

Example:

```
[{
        "animation_production_studios": [],
        "audio": ["English", "Japanese"]
}]
```

Comment: Include your code in the body of the question, don't use pictures of code

Comment: There are so many restrictions when trying to paste the code. Anyways, here is a sample: [
  {
    "animation_production_studios": [],
    "audio": [
      "English",
      "Japanese"
    ]]}]

Comment: The example should go with the question. I edited it on your behalf.

Comment: You should mention what is the expected output. There are many ways to convert an array to a string.

Comment: Expected output: audio element should have values: English, Japanese. And then insert these values into a db

Comment: That is a _shockingly_ lazy question. Please edit the question and include the expected output. Also, please state what you have tried, so that responders do not waste their time telling you to repeat those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe ????

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since no specific format is required for the output, I'll just concatenate the values separate by a comma. I use map at the payload level because it is an array. reduce() is the function I use to concatenate all the strings in audio into a single string.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ((item, index) -> item.audio reduce ((i, acc) -> acc ++ "," ++ i )) reduce ((i2, acc2) ->  acc2 ++ "," ++ i2 )
```

Input:

```
[{
        "animation_production_studios": [],
        "audio": ["English", "Japanese"]
},
{
        "animation_production_studios": [],
        "audio": ["German", "Spanish", "Italian"]
}
]
```

Output:

```
"English,Japanese,German,Spanish,Italian"
```

Comment: Thank Aled. But the output is still in an array. The requirement is to have it just as a string so as to insert into a db...?

Comment: Just use (payload map ((item, index) -> item.audio reduce ((i, acc) -> acc ++ "," ++ i )))[0] to get that element from the array.

Comment: Or you could do something like (payload.audio)[0] joinBy ","

Comment: Thanks Salim, it worked. Next thing I was looking for is to see if there is a way to remove the double quotes (""). I want the final output to be: English,Japanese

Comment: If "audio" array is in multiple objects, (payload.audio)[0] is always publishing the first available instance. how do we iterate this? Tried using map but getting error

Comment: can you publish a sample payload with multiple entries and the output that you expect?

Comment: As @SalimKhan asked, you should provide the expected output, and also the type. My output was JSON and in JSON a string absolutely has to have quotes. If the output were to be application/java to assign to a variable you would not see the variables. I'm updating my answer to output a single JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @aled ' s post but, to assume that is the correct desired output. All you need to do is:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
flatten(payload.*audio) joinBy  ","
```

[image: from dw playground:]